# O(1) Algorithm for Counting Left-Children in Complete Binary Tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

**I have a complete binary tree** (i.e. a tree where "every level, except possibly the last, is completely filled, and all nodes are as far left as possible").  **This tree is stored in depth-first, left-to-right order.  My problem is, given a node by index and the tree's total size, tell me how many nodes are in that node's left subtree, in O(1).**

---

For example, suppose the tree's total size is 10.  This implies the following complete tree (note: the numbers are the node index in the depth-first, left-to-right order):

```
      0
     / \
    1   7
   / \  |\
  2   5 8 9
 /|  /
3 4 6
```

Now, given a node index I need to find how many left-children it has.  For this example:

- Node 0 has 6 left-children.
- Node 1 has 3 left-children.
- Node 2 has 1 left-child.
- Node 3 has 0 left-children.
- Node 4 has 0 left-children.
- Node 5 has 1 left-child.
- Node 6 has 0 left-children.
- Node 7 has 1 left-child.
- Node 8 has 0 left-children.
- Node 9 has 0 left-children.

Each such query must take O(1) time and be a function only of the node index and tree size (e.g., I cannot store anything in the tree).

I feel like this should be a fairly simple problem, but so-far I haven't been able to figure it out.

---

<sup>Strictly speaking, this is a bit of a simplification of my problem; I actually want 1+ this value, and I'll never call the function on leaves.  But the core problem is this.</sup>

Comment: Is you tree also balanced? otherwise i don't think that without keeping  information in each node you can find number of nodes in left in O(1).

Comment: @LuaiGhunim A complete binary tree's topology is uniquely determined by the number of nodes it has.

Comment: Let l(i) and r(i) be the left and right children, respectively, of node i in DFS order. Then the number of left children of node i is lc(i) = r(i) - l(i) when both r(i) and l(i) are defined. (Leaves have no left children, and a node with just one child must have a left child that is itself a leaf.) Now all you need to do is figure out how to compute r(i) and l(i). l(i) is easy; r(i) will involve both the total number of nodes and the height h of the tree.

Comment: @chepner This is a good observation. Amusingly, my original problem is computing `r(i)-i`, so that I can go `i+=r(i)-i` to traverse right. I reduced it down to the stated problem (by `r(i)-i=1+lc(i)`), thinking it would be easier, and here you've changed it back :-)